# $\|x+y\|$ vs $\|x-y\|$ for reverse triangle inequality

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis

So I am using the text "Elementary Functional Analysis" by MacCluer. In it, for Exercise 1.1, it asks us to prove the Reverse Triangle Inequality (which I have done in the past, using the $x=(x-y)+y$ idea).

The issue I am running into is that MacCluer has written the inequality as such:

$\|x+y\|\geq \big|\|x\|-\|y\|\big|$

I am used to the reverse triangle inequality being written as:

$\|x-y\|\geq \big|\|x\|-\|y\|\big| $

Are these two equivalent, and if so, how would I go about proving it?

Comment: Substitute $z = -y$.

Comment: And this works because ||x|| = ||-x||, correct?

Comment: Yup, that' it. The two are equivalent because of that.

Answer (score 1):

Note that:
$$\|x+y\|=\|x-(-y)\||$$

Next use  reverse triangle inequality and $\|y\|=\|-y\|$:

$$\|x+y\|=\|x-(-y)\|\geq |\|x\|-\|-y\| |=|\|x\|-\|y\||$$